# ‘fatal: No destination configured to push to’ error when I do a 'git push'

Tags: git

I try to checkout a remote branch.

And then make a commit and then push.

I get `fatal: No destination configured to push to` error when I do a 'git push'.

Here is the sequence of commands I use:

```
$ git checkout remote/test-1.6
$ git checkout -b test-1.6
$ git commit -a -m "commit message"
$ git push
fatal: No destination configured to push to.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify both the remote alias and the branch you wish to push (if there are many branches and you only want to push one).

From [the docs for push](http://gitref.org/remotes/):

> [to commit to a remote repo] you run `git push [alias] [branch]` which will attempt to make your [branch] the new [branch] on the [alias] remote.

If you wish to push all branches to the remote repo (or only have one to push), you can omit the branch specifier and do a

```
git push [alias]
```

For your specific case, as Mike specified in his comment,

```
git push remote test-1.6
```

should work.

Answer (score 16):

You probably already have a remote for your repository, but your new branch hasn't been configured to use it. This should work:

```
git push --set-upstream remote test-1.6
```

Having done that once, there is now a tracking branch in place and you can simply use "git push" in future -- assuming you've configured upstream push of the current branch as the default, like so:

```
git config --global push.default tracking
```

Or (preferred) as of git 1.7.4:

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

Answer (score 4):

try to add a remote repo with

```
git remote add remote http://.../repo.git
```

then you can do a

```
git push remote test-1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

right you have to first add a remote

```
git remote add myremote  [url]
```

then you will be able to push using  :  `git push myremote master`  (or any other branch)